# CF DESEDE encrypt() Key Length Issue

Tags: encryption, coldfusion, coldfusion-8, 3des

I am trying to encrypt a string using ColdFusion encrypt() with a 3rd party provided key like this:

```
encrypteded = encrypt('theString', 'FD52250E230D1CDFD5C2DF0D57E3E0FEFD52250E230D1CDF', 'DESEDE/CBC/NoPadding', 'BASE64', ToBase64('0'));
```

I get:

> "The key specified is not a valid key for this encryption: Wrong key algorithm, expected DESede."

What do I have to do to this key in terms of encoding/decoding to get it into the right format?

Comment: In your code example, it looks like you are passing a variable name instead of the string literal of the key.  I assume this is a problem with your example, not your actual code, but just thought I'd check.

Comment: I apologize. After re-reading the parity-checking code, I realized it's looking for odd parity. Sorry for the wild-goose chase.

Comment: Ben, that was just a problem with the example, not actual code, but I've updated to prevent any more confusion.

Comment: Also as Edward M Smith mentioned, make sure you are using the same IV as the other party or you will get different results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, when using provided keys from other languages, you have to do a little gymnastics on it to get it into Base64.

Try this for the key argument:

```
 ToBase64(BinaryDecode('FD52250E230D1CDFD5C2DF0D57E3E0FEFD52250E230D1CDF','hex'))
```

But, to make this work for me, the input string needed to be a multiple of 8 bytes (because you're specifying NoPadding), and the IV needed to also be a multiple of 8 bytes.

So, this ended up working for me - not sure if you'll be able to decrypt it on the other end, tho, if the IV they're specifying is really what you've got listed there.

```
 encrypteded = encrypt('theStrin', ToBase64(BinaryDecode('FD52250E230D1CDFD5C2DF0D57E3E0FEFD52250E230D1CDF','hex')), 'DESEDE/CBC/NoPadding', 'BASE64', ToBase64('0000'));
```

No IV also worked as well (with different output, obviously):

```
encrypteded = encrypt('theStrin', ToBase64(BinaryDecode('FD52250E230D1CDFD5C2DF0D57E3E0FEFD52250E230D1CDF','hex')), 'DESEDE/CBC/NoPadding', 'BASE64');
```

If you've been given a Hex IV, then you can use it as such:

```
encrypteded = encrypt('theStrin', ToBase64(BinaryDecode('FD52250E230D1CDFD5C2DF0D57E3E0FEFD52250E230D1CDF','hex')), 'DESEDE/CBC/NoPadding', 'BASE64', BinaryDecode("7fe8585328e9ac7b","hex"));
```

Hopefully this is enough info to get you on your way!

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that seems off to me is the algorithm value you're using. Maybe try this?

```
encrypteded = encrypt('theString', 'FD52250E230D1CDFD5C2DF0D57E3E0FEFD52250E230D1CDF', 'DESEDE', 'BASE64', ToBase64('0'));
```

I don't know if the `/CBC/NoPadding` settings will be what you want, but I don't think they will be allowed in the algorithm argument.

Comment: adam, DESEDE/CBC/NoPadding is definitely what i need to use. Unfortunately that is also what is causing the problem.

Comment: Extra settings like /CBC/NoPadding are allowed in the algorithm. But as Edward M Smith mentioned, NoPadding means you have do any padding of strings yourself. ie Make sure the input strings are a multiple of 8 bytes.